# Highchart network node color and other options not taken into account

Tags: highcharts

When I use Highchart with the following chart definition, the color of the nodes are not changed, nor the color of the links, nor the size of the nodes etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qpbrv2nk/

Raw definition:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "networkgraph"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "networkgraph": {
      "keys": [
        "from",
        "to",
        "color",
        "marker"
      ]
    },
    "series": {
      "marker": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "nodes": [{
      "color": "#ebac23",
      "id": "vf_1",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_525",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_942",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_1229",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_653",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_734",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_781",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_814",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_1022",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_398",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_429",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_18",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_478",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_381",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_334",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_1230",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_446",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_1117",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_1294",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_989",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_1069",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_878",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_1197",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_1325",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_1086",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_1261",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_1245",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_974",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_1005",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_798",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_1101",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_1133",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_1070",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_1293",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_3389",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_1309",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_1166",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_350",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_733",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_669",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_1038",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_1085",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_589",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_1118",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_782",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_894",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_1150",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_461",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_509",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_670",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_1214",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_1182",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_414",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_573",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_1277",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_558",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_845",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_413",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_318",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_925",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_606",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_654",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_862",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_750",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_973",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_477",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_926",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_382",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_365",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_1054",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_1246",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_494",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_846",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_861",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_1262",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_637",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_462",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_718",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_1134",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_749",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_605",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_701",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_1021",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_686",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_621",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_430",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_1165",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_766",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_2",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_1",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_1198",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_877",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_542",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_1278",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_622",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_829",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_526",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_893",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_445",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_830",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_958",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_638",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_574",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_1149",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_349",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_1310",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_366",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_702",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_317",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_797",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_34",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_1053",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_1037",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_717",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_765",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#006e00",
      "id": "criterion_541",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#7cb5ec",
      "id": "criterion_813",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#434348",
      "id": "criterion_493",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#90ed7d",
      "id": "criterion_909",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f7a35c",
      "id": "criterion_333",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#8085e9",
      "id": "criterion_510",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f15c80",
      "id": "criterion_397",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#e4d354",
      "id": "criterion_1006",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#2b908f",
      "id": "criterion_1181",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#f45b5b",
      "id": "criterion_590",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#91e8e1",
      "id": "criterion_685",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b80058",
      "id": "criterion_33",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#008cf9",
      "id": "criterion_1213",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00bbad",
      "id": "criterion_957",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#d163e6",
      "id": "criterion_1326",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#b24502",
      "id": "criterion_941",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#ff9287",
      "id": "criterion_910",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#5954d6",
      "id": "criterion_990",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00c6f8",
      "id": "criterion_1102",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#878500",
      "id": "criterion_17",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "#00a76c",
      "id": "criterion_557",
      "marker": {
        "radius": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
        "from": "criterion_525",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_942",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1229",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_653",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_734",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_781",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_814",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1022",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_398",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_429",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_18",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_478",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_381",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_334",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1230",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_446",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1117",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1294",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_989",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1069",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_878",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1197",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1325",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1086",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1261",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1245",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_974",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1005",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_798",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1101",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1133",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1070",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1293",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_3389",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1309",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1166",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_350",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_733",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_669",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1038",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1085",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_589",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1118",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_782",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_894",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1150",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_461",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_509",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_670",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
      {
        "from": "criterion_1214",
        "marker": {
          "dashStyle": "dash",
          "lineColor": "#ff0000",
          "lineWidth": 2
        },
        "to": "vf_1"
      },
    ],
    "tooltip": [],
    "type": "networkgraph"
  }],
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  }
});
```

I tried modifying the plotOptions, didn't work. I only managed to change the color of the lines by adding a color key, but couldn't make more and didn't understand why it didn't work.
Indeed, in this example, https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/, very few things were set. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed nodes in the incorrect location within the chart options. They should be in:

```
series.networkgraph.nodes
```

**Check the simplified demo for the reference:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b4zqcpx5/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.nodes

Comment: Arf, it was really dumb. Ty!